# How do I save values in database from an angular js phone.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I save values in database from an angular js phone.  my url  is http://jaymandhata.com/insure/quote#/form/profile  and i am unable to do login functionality.

Please send me steps or a guide to make it working.

Comment: 'angular js phone'?  What's that? Other than not knowing what device you are talking about, saving data from an Angular app is done just like any other website. You send the data you want to save to your backend, and your backend code handles the data and puts it in your database. Here's a small guide for a login though: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx

Comment: How do i save means? AngularJS is client side. You can collect data from user and trigger an ajax request to send the data to server. And there you need to have some server side code to handle the data.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks . By mistake i write phone. Its Angulat JS only. Please let me know exactly what steps i have to take to save data in database as I am trying but its not saving.